# How to figure out what metrics I can monitor while setting Keras Callbacks?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I am trying to figure out whether I have a host of metrics available to monitor out of the box while writing callbacks such as

```
ModelCheckpoint(monitor='val_loss')

or 

ModelCheckpoint(monitor='val_accuracy')
```

or whether the metrics i can monitor only depend on what i initialize in the `compile` method,

```
model.compile(metrics=['val_accuracy', 'val_loss'])

vs

model.compile(metrics=['val_loss'])

or 

model.compile(metrics=['loss'])
```

**Question**: Does initializing the callback come with a host of metrics i can monitor out of the box or do I have to manually set the metrics in the model compilation step, which constrains me to only those that I wrote?

**Side Question**: How can I find out the whole host of metrics I can type in whether it is in the `compile` method or not.. because I can't seem to find a source that tells me.

Comment: Check [the tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint) for more information on the different values you can give for the monitor argument, specifically the point on the `history.history` dictionary.

Comment: @Oxbowerce I'm not sure I understand why you can only see the metrics after you fit the data. I mean it's a bit counter intuitive. I would want to set the metrics to monitor before i fit the data.

Comment: That is not the only way to doing it, as metioned in the docs you can also pass in (custom) `metrics.Metric` objects. [Here is the list of all tensorflow metrics.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics)